# Como ocultar propriedades de uma entidade de modelo ASP.NET Core apenas na renderizaçao do JSON?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

Estou começando os estudos com ASP.NET core Web Api, e estou implementando a classe Usuario, que possui uma propriedade Senha.
Logicamente não quero que a senha seja visivel nos JSONs da api.

Andei pesquisando bastante, li sobre IgnoreDataMember, DataContract, DataMember etc... mas o comportamento deles é um pouco radical demais, ou seja, quando adiciono uma anotação IgnoreDataMember na propriedade senha ele não exibe a senha no objeto Usuário, mas também não consegue fazer o bind da propriedade Senha do Usuario quando vem em uma requisição POST por exemplo.

Gostaria de uma forma de que essa propriedade não aparecesse no JSON de resposta, mas ainda estivesse disponível para utilização dentro do sistema.

Antes de concluir, eu conheço o padrão ViewModel, e sei que posso criar uma classe apenas com os parâmetros que eu quero exibir, mas sinceramente, acho esse padrão de projeto extremamente verboso (escreve-se demais para implementar). Sei que em última instancia eu vou utilizar isso mesmo, mas gostaria de ter uma outra opção mais elegante.

Obrigado pela atenção!

Comment: Tem o código que gera esse retorno?

Comment: O ideal é que você nem armazene a senha informada para o usuário e sim criar uma hash no momento do cadastro, como por exemplo o MD5 do login + senha... e seria esse resultado que você usaria para validar se os dados que o usuário inputou conferem com o cadastro que você tem.

Comment: Acredito que o ideal é você utilizar ViewModel para levar para sua view só os campos que devem ser mostrados e quando retornar vc pode usar o autommaper para transformar para o model.
Vou deixar aqui um link de referencia: [Clique Aqui](http://www.eduardopires.net.br/2013/08/asp-net-mvc-view-model-pattern-quando-e-como-utilizar/)

Comment: use o   [JsonIgnore] Assembly Newtonsoft.Json

Comment: @LeandroAngelo, sim, eu já faço um hash a partir da senha do usuário, porém, nem mesmo esse hash eu gostaria de exibir, uma vez que pode ser utilizado para buscas em bases de senhas no estilo md5 decript (eu sei que não é uma desencriptação, e sim uma busca em base de dados)

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza, no caso, o ASP.NET Core utiliza um parser próprio para o retorno, e francamente não gostaria de alterá-lo, uma vez que a idéia é utilizar o framework o mais puro possível. Adicionar o Newtonsoft foi cogitado, porém não está no projeto no momento.

Comment: @RodrigoPortilio, , é... estou chegando a mesma conclusão, embora eu continue achando que o ViewModel é um modelo extremamente verboso de se codificar, uma vez que tenho basicamente que fazer um clone da entidade de usuário apenas para remover uma propriedade. Num futuro, sempre que uma propriedade nova aparecer, são mais dois lugares pra ajustar.
Caso faça dessa forma, acredito que não vou utilizar o Automapper, uma vez que o sistema está em expansão, sendo necessária alteração nos mappers a cada nova entidade implementada.